# Main in static inner class produces ClassnotFoundException (despite $)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, inner-classes, java-11

I'm using Java 11 and IntelliJ. See the snippet below:

```java
public class Outer {
    public static class InnerA {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }

    public static class InnerB {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }
}
```

This results in no compile errors, but I cannot run it. Running it in the IDE result in a `ClassNotFoundException`

I tried using bash:

```
$ java Outer$InnerA.java
```

Which yields:

```
error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: Outer
```

I've tried rebuilding the project with no success.

**Edit:**

Since java 11 it is possible to execute a class without compiling it (`javac`). If I add a `main()` to `Outer.java` and execute it in the IDE or if I type the following in bash:

```
java Outer.java
```

Then the `main()` of `Outer.java` class is successfully called.

Comment: `java Outer$InnerA.java` is not a valid command. You cannot run a source file. If you've already compiled it, just do `java Outer$InnerA` without the .java file extension. If not, use `javac` instead of `java`

Comment: It is valid in Java 11. If I add a main() in Outer and call `java Outer.java` it does work as intended.

Comment: Sorry, haven't been keeping up with the latest releases. However, `Outer$InnerA.java` still isn't a source file, so I don't think it should work.  Don't take my word for it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer myself.

## IntelliJ:

I was using Gradle as my build tool. In IntelliJ this seems not to work. After I've change it to "IntelliJ IDEA" (see screenshot), I was finally was able to run it.

[image: Build Settings]

## Bash:

Considering the new Java 11 feature i.e. "[launching single-file programs](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330)", it seems it's not possible to run an inner static class like this way.

So after compiling and escaping the "$", I was able to run the file with:

```
$ java Outer\$InnerA
```

Thanks to [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11882002/user) for hinting into the right direction.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Reported the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-242930

Comment: The “launch single-file programs” feature requires you to specify the *file name* and you can’t mix the file name with the name of the inner class. Then, it will run the first class defined in the single source code file. Obviously, it is impossible for a nested class to be the first defined, as the definition of its outer class must start before it.